# How to calculate turning acceleration from a compass?

Tags: mathematics

I have degree and timestamp and want to calculate the turning acceleration. I what to trigger some code when the compass is turning fast. Is there a mathematic way to get an turning acceleration parameter? Tried my self but it got complexed when the compass goes from ex. 363deg to 21deg via the 0deg :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: for finding out the turning/angular acceleration say $\alpha$, you need to know the angular displacement say $\theta$ as a function of the time $t$ then $$\alpha=\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$$